# How can frameworks build anything complex and permanent given the fallibility of memory?

Tags: skepticism, memory, foundations

Imagine you start your framework with some facts.

Now, you then derive some statement. Can you hold the entire chain of inference in your mind simultaneously? If not, then that statement is dependent on the soundness of your memories claiming that each step in the chain was indeed correct.

So, it seems the only solution is to take memory to be infallible as an axiom of the framework. That could easily be refuted, however, and suddenly, the framework contains a contradiction.

It seems we can only ever know facts that are, right then, being held in one's mind simultaneously as the basic truths they come from (in the event of foundationalism), or facts that exist within a loop which is, in its entirety, being held in one's mind  (in the event of coherentism).

This severely restricts the framework. How can one deal with this?

**EDIT:**

I just began reading [this SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/memory-episprob/) on the matter; hopefully it shows the issue being dealt with.

**EDIT 2:**

The linked-to article definitely acknowledges this as a fundamental issue (see the last chapter, *The Reliability of Memory*). As for solutions though, I found it lacking. I have read through it quite quickly, but my first read-through makes it seem like the different responses are mostly begging the question or allowing the problem.

Comment: Memory is irrelevant here. Even if we could hold all of that in our mind simultaneously (I am not even sure what that means) we couldn't reliably process it all. So we know that *everything* in our frameworks is fallible and impermanent. How does it prevent complexity and where is the contradiction? The Earth is limited in resources and impermanent too, it grew plenty complex over those billions of years it managed to stick around nonetheless.

Comment: @Conifold Consider this idea: a square with a circle in it. If you are not aphantasic, you can likely visualize it in its entirety, thus keeping the constituent ideas in your mind simultaneously. Without visualization, it might be possible too, though I am not so sure; we can non-visually read the ideas out in our head, but thus seemingly not achieve a simultaneous apprehension of them. Now, reasoning is just a sequence of ideas, and unless one can apprehend the entire sequence simultaneously, then memory because a potentially fallible middle-man. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] And if memory is unavoidable for sufficiently complex ideas/chains of reasons, and if memory is fallible, then building a framework with any considerable level of complexity becomes impossible; and one only knows the parts of the framework one actually apprehends; the rest of the unapprehended framework is just remembered as true. If one accepts this, without offering any solution, then one is accepting Pyrrhonist skepticism for whenever one isn't apprehending one's framework.

Comment: That's why things are written down.

Comment: First of all, a gold star for what seems to be an original argument for skepticism. Second, you need to unapack *recall fallibility* if memory serves that is. 

Comment: Our "apprehending of the entire sequence simultaneously" is as fallible as our memory. I don't see why anyone should think that simultaneity and visualization possess some infallible magic. And hence why one only knows what they "apprehend simultaneously". "Complexity is impossible without infallibility" is factually false, and in any case, comes out of nowhere as well. The entire argument is based on unsupported assertions that no one needs to accept.

Comment: @kutschkem Perhaps you mean that this helps the issue by externalizing the framework, so that it exists regardless of the thinker's fallible mind? That in itself is problematic, but also does nothing to alleviate the problem of those fallible thinkers deriving knowledge from the framework. Perhaps you mean that writing it down completely removes the need for memory? If so, I ask you to keep an entire 5000-word text in your mind at once.

Comment: @Conifold "Our "apprehending of the entire sequence simultaneously" is as fallible as our memory." That is debatable and outside of the scope of this Q. Even if it is as fallible, it is on some level fallible in a different way. During simultaneous apprehension, memory cannot serve as a source of error. Also, the claim that I made of which your quote likely alludes to was that considerable (to me, a subjective matter) complexity is unachievable if one cannot justify propositions with propositions of the form "I remember A,B,C,...X, to be true".

Comment: @AgentSmith Thanks :), though I would be surprised if this is original; it seems the article I am currently reading (linked in the Q) deals with this, but I cannot say for sure yet. As for the second part of your comment; are you saying I need to explore the different ways memory may introduce errors?

Comment: @user1113719, yes and it looks quite complicated from where I'm at.

Comment: You can like, take notes

Comment: @armand See my response to  kutschkem.

Comment: In your every day life you memorize way more information than is necessary to handle a philosophical framework. If our memory was as bad as you need it to be for your skepticism to make sense, we'd be dead by now, or at least unable of having any social or professional life. So while not perfect it must be good enough. Of course you could argue my memories of having friends and a career are fake, but that would be entering the desperate land of hypercriticism, from which no useful idea ever emerged. Without a reason to suspect our memory is that bad, why waste time supposing it's the case?

Comment: @armand First of all, do not confuse helpful ideas with true ideas. If a helpful idea falls to Pyrrhonistic skepticism, then I cannot simply assert it to be true for the sake of enjoying its helpfulness; though I can still act according to it without claiming it to be true. Furthermore, to doubt one's memory in cases of "I have a memory of previously having proved this to be the case, but I cannot be sure this is true" is not being extremely skeptical. If you are dealing with a lot of propositions that are subtly different, it is not unlikely for the proof of one to be confused with another.

Comment: Since the truth of any idea is unknowable to us, helpful beats true anytime and is simply the best you can hope for. You claim to be skeptic about your memory to the point you can't handle a syllogism, but still answer as if you remember who you're talking to and push arguments forward. Funny... Like every hypercritic you don't put your money where your mouth is. Have fun wasting your time if you're so inclined.

Comment: "Since the truth of any idea is unknowable to us, (...)", I do not assume this. I have, from a place of no assumptions, been able to create an island of knowledge that is known so long as it is apprehended (a lá *cogito, ergo sum*). I hope to expand it; maybe I cannot, and if so, I will settle for helpful, in lieu of true. Also, to argue for the fallibility of memory using memory is fine; either you assume memory is infallible, in which case the argument stands and thus causes a contradiction; or, you do not assume memory is infallible, and thus arrive at the same place. This is basic.