# Arguments against personal omphalism

Tags: time, descartes, skepticism

*Personal omphalism* is, for  a lack of a better term (let me know if you know of a better word), what I call the possibility of one's own mind having come into existence at any point, with one's apparent past simply being constructed memories; varieties of this include the possibilities of Boltzmann brains and malevolent demons.

This is related to [my question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97771/how-can-frameworks-build-anything-complex-and-permanent-given-the-fallibility-of) on memory skepticism, which  I think I might have a solution for. That solution necessitates that the memories in-question refer to actual past events, something which is placed under doubt when considering the possibility of personal omphalism.

So, what arguments exist against personal omphalism?

Comment: Why would you believe in personal omphalism to begin with? The fact that there is no argument *for* it is in and of itself a very good argument *against* it. It's like asking why I should not believe in the immaterial invisible dragon that throws heatless flames in my garage.

Comment: Why "Descartes" tag?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I'm guessing 'malevolent demons' is meant to be a reference to "I suppose there exists an extremely powerful, and, if I may so speak, malignant being, whose whole endeavors are directed toward deceiving me" of Cartesian Scepticism.

Comment: @armand Your opinion that having no argument for something being an argument against that something is a very slippery slope. At the end of the chain of arguments, what arguments have you? If none, then you have an argument against the entire chain, by your logic.

Comment: @user1113719 you're having it completely backward. It's you who's on a slippery slope. By your logic you now have to believe about every single idea that has no argument for it, and there is an infinity of those: pixies, talking dogs, mermaids... The only reason you apply this very strange epistemic standard only to your pet theory is special pleading, but if you start applying it equally then anything goes. First you need a reason to emit the hypothesis that the world was created 25 minutes ago, something that wouldn't make sense otherwise. Is there such a thing? No. Then why waste your time?

Comment: @armand I never said I believed in personal omphalism; I'm withholding assent. That is a slippery slope from a pragmatic view however; all things that cannot be disproven, I must withhold assent of, damaging my ability to make definitive statements (for now). However, my absolute skepticism is leading me to more and more absolutely certain results, and soon, I will not need to withhold assent about most of these ridiculous and annoying propositions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that personal omphalism is false since by definition, it matches all observations. If it doesn’t, you can just modify it ad hoc. But that makes the theory untestable. Therefore, there is no reason to believe it since you can come up with any number of untestable theories to explain literally any phenomenon ever.

Having no reason to believe something is itself an argument against that position, and that is ultimately all that matters.

Comment: You couldn't disprove it empirically, but logically, perhaps?

Comment: There’s nothing contradictory about the concept.

Comment: Nothing self-contradictory (as far as I can tell), but it may contradict with different frameworks.

Comment: If it’s not self contradictory it’s not logically contradictory. Therefore it can’t be disproven

Comment: You would have to explain why other people have memories of you from before your supposed 'start' time.

Comment: @thinkingman *Being contradictory* is a relative term; a proposition is not simply contradictory; a proposition is **in contradiction** with something. That something can be the proposition itself, or some framework/theory.